# How to make Kafka broker respond retriable or non-retriable errors to the consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Our project runs in Docker containers. We want to test that our consumer code behaves as expected on broker errors (both retriable or nonretriable errors are fine).

I tried removing the Leader Kafka container, but the underline library got "Error connecting to node" instead of consumer getting an error suitable for our test.
I tried removing the zookeeper container, and the consumer and the producer still worked without getting any errors. We don't use authentication. Otherwise, authentication error might be an easy one to produce.

How to make Kafka broker respond retriable or non-retriable errors to the consumer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
For retryable errors, I found this. 

https://kafka.js.org/docs/configuration#retry
https://kafka.js.org/docs/configuration#restart-on-failure
https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_codes

For non-retryable errors, I have not found anything yet. But it looks like we need to handle it by ourselves using catch. I will post if I find anything.
```